# Timestamp conversion missmatching?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, unix-timestamp

I have a database in which i want to save readable timestamps ass strings with a specific format.
The input-dataframe I get has timstamps of type 'timestamp'.
For calculations I convert them to unix-timestamps. The results go back to a database as a string formatted timestamp.
The problem is, that when I convert these string-formatted timestamps back to unix I have missmatching values.

How can that happen?

```py
time_format = "YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz"
dummy = df.withColumn('start_time_unix', f.unix_timestamp('start_time'))\
          .withColumn('start_time_string', f.from_unixtime('start_time_unix', format=time_format))\
          .withColumn('start_time_unix_2', f.unix_timestamp('start_time_string', format=time_format))                          
dummy.printSchema()
dummy.show(10, False)
```

```
OUTPUT
root
 |-- start_time: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- start_time_unix: long (nullable = true)
 |-- start_time_string: string (nullable = true)
 |-- start_time_unix_2: long (nullable = true)

+-------------------+---------------+-----------------------+-----------------+
|start_time         |start_time_unix|start_time_string      |start_time_unix_2|
+-------------------+---------------+-----------------------+-----------------+
|2019-06-04 00:39:08|1559601548     |2019-06-04T00:39:08CEST|1546123148       |
+-------------------+---------------+-----------------------+-----------------+
```

EDIT

The input-dataframe was generated according to:

```py
df = spark.read.csv('data.csv', header=True, inferSchema=True)
```

With the csv containing rows like: "2019-06-04 00:39:08" (without ")

Comment: I'm curious as to how the data was inserted.  I see this when there is an implied format in an APP (via the client) and UTC on the server, however your values are off by more than one hour, which leaves me with a question - not an answer.

Comment: I added a short description about how I created the input-dataframe. And yes, the fact that the time-difference in more than one or two hours is strange to me.